Java grpc client batches message responses for async unary calls
We have the following code that is used to retrieve events from a gRPC server on our backend and then resolve events (in the order they are received). It's supposed to do this asynchronously to increase throughput, especially because some of the events might resolve slowly which should not block other event resolution processes.
The code looks like this:
package com.coyoapp.trap.client.impl.connection;

import com.coyoapp.trap.client.api.TrapDataSource;
import com.coyoapp.trap.client.impl.StateUpdateProcessor;
import com.coyoapp.trap.client.impl.metrics.EventTimestampMetricsProcessor;
import com.coyoapp.trap.client.impl.metrics.TrapMetricsFacade;
import com.coyoapp.trap.grpcmessages.EventServiceGrpc;
import com.coyoapp.trap.grpcmessages.Events;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter;
import io.grpc.CallOptions;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannel;
import io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

/**
 * Connection to a data source that handles event resolving asynchronously.
 * Extends {@link DataSourceConnection}.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("UnstableApiUsage")
public class AsyncDataSourceConnection extends DataSourceConnection {
    private static final Duration WORKER_THREAD_TERMINATE_TIMEOUT = Duration.ofSeconds(30);
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncDataSourceConnection.class);
    private final RateLimiter rateLimiter;
    private final BlockingQueue<EventResponseFuture> eventQueue;
    private final TrapMetricsFacade metricsFacade;
    private final Thread queueWorker;
    private static final DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    AsyncDataSourceConnection(ManagedChannel grpcChannel,
                              TrapDataSource dataSource,
                              StateUpdateProcessor processor,
                              EventTimestampMetricsProcessor eventTimestampMetricsProcessor,
                              TrapMetricsFacade metricsFacade,
                              float rateLimit, int maxQueueSize) {
        super(grpcChannel, dataSource, processor, eventTimestampMetricsProcessor);
        decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
        this.metricsFacade = metricsFacade;
        rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(rateLimit);
        eventQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(maxQueueSize);
        queueWorker = new Thread(this::processQueue, "TrapEventQueueWorker");
        queueWorker.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Events.EventResponse event) {
        metricsFacade.registerGauge("internal_event_queue_size", eventQueue.size(), v -> (double) v);
        //rateLimiter.acquire();
        log.info("Enqueuing event [{}] for type [{}] with queue size [{}]", event.getId(), event.getEntityType(), eventQueue.size());
        super.onNext(event);
    }

    /**
     * Enqueues the event and starts the loading for the event response.
     * Events are maintained in a queue and a list for easy retrieval of the queued event state on completion.
     *
     * @param event event
     */
    @Override
    protected void handleEvent(Events.EventResponse event) {
        var queueEntry = new QueuedEventResponse(event);
        EventResponseFuture future = new EventResponseFuture(queueEntry);
        try {
            eventQueue.put(future); // with timeout maybe? offer()
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        var clientCall =
            grpcChannel.newCall(EventServiceGrpc.getGetEventMethod(), CallOptions.DEFAULT);
        Events.StateRequest request =
            Events.StateRequest.newBuilder().setId(event.getId()).build();
        queueEntry.startTiming();
        ClientCalls.asyncUnaryCall(clientCall, request, future);
    }

    @Override
    public void close(String reason) {
        super.close(reason);
        queueWorker.interrupt();
        try {
            queueWorker.join(WORKER_THREAD_TERMINATE_TIMEOUT.toMillis());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            log.error("Error while terminating event queue worker");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("java:S2189")
    private void processQueue() {
        try {
            do {
                EventResponseFuture eventResponseFuture = eventQueue.take();
                processEvent(eventResponseFuture);
            } while (true);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            log.info("Queue worker terminated");
        }
    }

    private void processEvent(EventResponseFuture eventResponseFuture) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            QueuedEventResponse queuedEvent = eventResponseFuture.get();
            log.info("External processing for event [{}] for type [{}] took [{}]s",
                    queuedEvent.getEventResponse().getId(), queuedEvent.getEventResponse().getEntityType(),
                    queuedEvent.getDurationInSeconds());
            long internalProcessingStart = System.nanoTime();
            processor.processEvent(queuedEvent.getStateResponse(), queuedEvent.getEventResponse());
            long internalProcessingEnd = System.nanoTime();
            log.info("Internal processing for event [{}] took [{}]s",
                    queuedEvent.getEventResponse().getId(),
                    decimalFormat.format((internalProcessingEnd - internalProcessingStart) / 1_000_000_000.0));
        } catch (RuntimeException | ExecutionException e) {
            log.error("Error while processing event queue", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Queued event response data object.
     * This object holds the event and eventually the state response for the event.
     */
    static class QueuedEventResponse {
        private Events.StateResponse stateResponse;
        private final Events.EventResponse event;
        private long startTime;
        private long endTime;


        QueuedEventResponse(Events.EventResponse event) {
            this.event = event;
        }

        void setStateResponse(Events.StateResponse stateResponse) {
            log.info("State loaded for event [{}] for type [{}]",
                    event.getId(), event.getEntityType());
            this.stateResponse = stateResponse;
            this.endTime = System.nanoTime();
        }

        Events.StateResponse getStateResponse() {
            return stateResponse;
        }

        Events.EventResponse getEventResponse() {
            return event;
        }

        void startTiming() {
            this.startTime = System.nanoTime();
        }

        String getDurationInSeconds() {
            return decimalFormat.format((endTime - startTime) / 1_000_000_000.0);
        }
    }

    static class EventResponseFuture extends CompletableFuture<QueuedEventResponse>
            implements io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver<Events.StateResponse> {
        private final QueuedEventResponse event;

        public EventResponseFuture(QueuedEventResponse event) {
            this.event = event;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Events.StateResponse stateResponse) {
            event.setStateResponse(stateResponse);
            complete(event);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            Events.EventResponse eventResponse = event.getEventResponse();
            log.error("Error while loading state for event [{}] for type [{}]",
                    eventResponse.getId(), eventResponse.getEntityType(), t);
            completeExceptionally(t);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}

We tried everything we could come up with to make sure our code does not introduce any bottlenecks except those by design (queue order, throttling, queue size). What is strange is that the timing of the external processing (aka, the gRPC event resolution duration) shows the same duration for all messages per queue size. E.g. The internal queue is filled up with events, then the client sits still for a while, then the events resolve all at the same time and show roughly the same processing duration.
We tried a queue size of 100 messages on our staging environment and the processing time skyrocketed to 160 SECONDS for all 100 events (and they all came back at the same time). Even in the worst case scenario where the head event in the queue takes the longest time to resolve, it should not scale the duration of all events like that.
The events should complete and sit in the queue, waiting for the future of the first event to complete, then pour out and log their specific timings. But all 100 events showed a processing time of around 160 seconds.
The messages we are receiving are not very large (couple of byte to kB's) but we need to work through hundreds of millions of messages.
What we can gather from that is that netty-gRPC is somehow batching those requests internally and only releases them when they are all complete, which is exactly what we do not want.
Is this the case? Or is there another explanation?
The code for the channel creation looks like this:
private ManagedChannel createGrpcChannel(TrapDataSource dataSource) {
        return ManagedChannelBuilder
                .forTarget(dataSource.getSource())
                .keepAliveTime(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .keepAliveWithoutCalls(true)
                .executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())
                .maxInboundMessageSize(trapClientProperties.getMaxIncomingMessageSize())
                .usePlaintext()
                .build();
    }

An example of the behavior can be seen in this log:
2024-12-19T13:37:07.881+01:00 TRACE 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.h.c.c.trap.impl.TrapStateStoreImpl     : save(id: c1bc4579-4401-4360-b141-1ba982876e37, tenantId: 849faf64-f6e0-4b1c-a024-d82d82afd7ee, origin: PAST)
2024-12-19T13:37:07.881+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-4] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : Enqueuing event [331] for type [TENANT] with queue size [40]
2024-12-19T13:37:07.882+01:00 TRACE 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.h.c.c.a.i.AppOwnershipUpdateHandler    : onEntityUpdated(c1bc4579-4401-4360-b141-1ba982876e37)
2024-12-19T13:37:07.882+01:00 TRACE 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.h.c.c.s.i.SenderOwnershipUpdateHandler : onEntityUpdated(c1bc4579-4401-4360-b141-1ba982876e37)
2024-12-19T13:37:07.882+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : Internal processing for event [200] took [0,01]s
2024-12-19T13:37:07.882+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : External processing for event [201] for type [WORKSPACE] took [0,8]s
2024-12-19T13:37:07.882+01:00 TRACE 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.h.c.c.trap.impl.TrapStateStoreImpl     : update(id: c1bc4579-4401-4360-b141-1ba982876e37, tenantId: 849faf64-f6e0-4b1c-a024-d82d82afd7ee, origin: PAST)
2024-12-19T13:37:07.884+01:00 TRACE 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.h.c.c.a.i.AppOwnershipUpdateHandler    : onEntityUpdated(c1bc4579-4401-4360-b141-1ba982876e37)
2024-12-19T13:37:07.884+01:00 TRACE 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.h.c.c.s.i.SenderOwnershipUpdateHandler : onEntityUpdated(c1bc4579-4401-4360-b141-1ba982876e37)
2024-12-19T13:37:07.884+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : Internal processing for event [201] took [0,01]s
2024-12-19T13:37:07.884+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : External processing for event [202] for type [APP] took [0,79]s
2024-12-19T13:37:07.884+01:00 TRACE 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.h.c.c.trap.impl.TrapStateStoreImpl     : save(id: e83acd05-90da-448b-ad6e-82bb19b64e7f, tenantId: 849faf64-f6e0-4b1c-a024-d82d82afd7ee, origin: PAST)
2024-12-19T13:37:07.885+01:00 TRACE 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.h.c.c.a.i.AppOwnershipUpdateHandler    : onEntityUpdated(e83acd05-90da-448b-ad6e-82bb19b64e7f)
2024-12-19T13:37:07.885+01:00 TRACE 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.h.c.c.c.impl.ContentAppUpdateHandler   : onEntityCreatedOrUpdated(e83acd05-90da-448b-ad6e-82bb19b64e7f)
2024-12-19T13:37:07.891+01:00 TRACE 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.h.c.c.s.i.SenderOwnershipUpdateHandler : onEntityUpdated(e83acd05-90da-448b-ad6e-82bb19b64e7f)
2024-12-19T13:37:07.893+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : Internal processing for event [202] took [0,01]s
2024-12-19T13:37:13.032+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-4] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [203] for type [FILE]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.032+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : External processing for event [203] for type [FILE] took [5,51]s
2024-12-19T13:37:13.032+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-5] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [277] for type [USER]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.032+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-4] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [273] for type [TARGET_SEGMENTS]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.032+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-4] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [271] for type [TARGET_SEGMENTS]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.033+01:00 TRACE 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.h.c.c.trap.impl.TrapStateStoreImpl     : save(id: 433be062-535c-4398-a6dc-7332eb5c47f6::c1bc4579-4401-4360-b141-1ba982876e37, tenantId: 849faf64-f6e0-4b1c-a024-d82d82afd7ee, origin: PAST)
2024-12-19T13:37:13.033+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-5] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [255] for type [USER]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.033+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-1] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [254] for type [API_CLIENT]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.033+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-4] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [269] for type [TARGET_SEGMENTS]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.033+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-5] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [245] for type [USER]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.033+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-4] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [244] for type [USER]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.033+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-4] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [242] for type [FILE]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.033+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-4] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [230] for type [TIMELINE_ITEM]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.033+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-5] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [222] for type [TIMELINE_ITEM]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.033+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-4] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [219] for type [TIMELINE_ITEM]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.033+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-5] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [215] for type [TIMELINE_ITEM]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.033+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-5] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [214] for type [TIMELINE_ITEM]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.033+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-5] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [213] for type [EVENT]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.033+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-5] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [211] for type [EVENT]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.033+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-5] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [210] for type [EVENT]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.034+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-5] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [208] for type [EVENT]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.034+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-5] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [206] for type [EVENT]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.034+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [pool-4-thread-4] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : State loaded for event [205] for type [EVENT]
2024-12-19T13:37:13.035+01:00 TRACE 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.h.c.c.a.i.AppOwnershipUpdateHandler    : onEntityUpdated(433be062-535c-4398-a6dc-7332eb5c47f6::c1bc4579-4401-4360-b141-1ba982876e37)
2024-12-19T13:37:13.035+01:00 TRACE 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.h.c.c.s.i.SenderOwnershipUpdateHandler : onEntityUpdated(433be062-535c-4398-a6dc-7332eb5c47f6::c1bc4579-4401-4360-b141-1ba982876e37)
2024-12-19T13:37:13.037+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : Internal processing for event [203] took [0,01]s
2024-12-19T13:37:13.037+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : External processing for event [205] for type [EVENT] took [5,51]s
2024-12-19T13:37:13.037+01:00 TRACE 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.h.c.c.trap.impl.TrapStateStoreImpl     : save(id: ab38f715-e08a-4a7c-baf1-89a8c4c19676, tenantId: 849faf64-f6e0-4b1c-a024-d82d82afd7ee, origin: PAST)
2024-12-19T13:37:13.039+01:00 TRACE 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.h.c.c.a.i.AppOwnershipUpdateHandler    : onEntityUpdated(ab38f715-e08a-4a7c-baf1-89a8c4c19676)
2024-12-19T13:37:13.039+01:00 TRACE 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.h.c.c.s.i.SenderOwnershipUpdateHandler : onEntityUpdated(ab38f715-e08a-4a7c-baf1-89a8c4c19676)
2024-12-19T13:37:13.039+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : Internal processing for event [205] took [0,01]s
2024-12-19T13:37:13.039+01:00  INFO 15188 --- [content-connector] [ventQueueWorker] c.c.t.c.i.c.AsyncDataSourceConnection    : External processing for event [206] for type [EVENT] took [5,51]s

As you can see there is a 5 second gap after which alle queued events resolve at the same time with roughly the same duration.
We tried multiple different approaches to multithreading, including looping threads that check the queue with a non-blocking queue. We also set the config values for the rate limiter (and removing the rate limiter) and max channel inbound message size to very high values. No approach showed any different results.
